# Linux console app built with binary library works on my machine, but not on others with same Linux version

Tags: c++, linux

I have a Linux application written in C++ with proprietary source code so this question is about any mechanisms that could cause what I describe below to happen.

Anyway, the application uses some library functions that perform some data processing and spits out a result. On my machine, I get the expected result. On others, the app either segfaults or outputs nonsense.

It is distributed as a bit of source code and a static library, built on my machine, which can then be built with `make` and run (and possibly distributed). The OS environment is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (WSL1) and is essentially the same on all of the machines.

The `ldd` utility indicates that the same libraries are being used and the Ubuntu and g++ versions are identical as well.

The application was run in `gdb` on one of the machines where it segfaults and it turned out that a specific buffer hadn't been allocated and was `nullptr`. The size parameter being passed to the constructor in this case is a `#define` macro.

I am aware that the preferred approach on Linux is to distribute source code, not precompiled binaries, but for IP protection purposes, that might not always be possible. I have also read that there could be subtle library version or kernel-level incompatibilities that can cause this kind of weirdness, but like I said, that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Q: Does anybody know why I might be observing this strange behavior?

Comment: The specific processor architecture might be relevant here?

Comment: @BenGillett 64-bit Intel.

Comment: Is it same processor on all target archs?

Comment: Without more details, it is very hard to help.

Comment: @P.P I don't think so. Some are i5s and some i7s. It's possible they might be different generations.

Comment: This needs more detail. The processor where you have built may have more features than the target processor (you can compare `grep flags /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u` on both machines). On the failing system, run your binary under gdb and check where exactly it  segaults: `gdb ./binary  -> run -> disassem`. This will give you the clue on the missing features.

Comment: @P.P I added information about our gdb session. Will try your suggestions as well. Thanks

Comment: @dandan78 That doesn't make much sense. How come a `#define` value not getting passed and the buffer not getting allocated? My guess is that there are other issues (alignment, missing processor features, etc). In general, when doing such binary/library distribution, you have to use the "lowest common denominator" in terms of library (libstdc++), compiler, kernel, processor and so on to build the library/binary.

Comment: @P.P I agree. It doesn't make sense at all. I hadn't considered the lowest common denominator aspect, though.

Comment: Did you use any compiler flags (or linker flags) when building your binary executable? If you don't explicitly use any architecture-specific build options then the "lowest common denominator" is ensured by the default build options of the compiler (and linker). That is, of course, true only for the build tools provided with the OS (so installed from the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories in your case).

Another thing – Is the nullptr buffer allocated inside the statically-linked library you mention? Or inside some shared object? The behaviour your'e describing can be a result of some linkage issues.

Comment: @Tomek Yes, good point, I was just looking into that myself. The default is indeed `-march=x86-64`. The offending buffer is in the statically-linked library. The only linker options are several `-l`s

Comment: So this is quite strange. Personally I would try to first `make clean` and rebuild (if you haven't tried that already) and if that doesn't help I would double-check if perhaps your build environment isn't the odd one (and it works fine there accidentally) – restart your build environment, run your app without rebuilding it and see if it still works correctly. This second test is to check if the issue isn't really somewhere in your source code and only accidentally it works on your build machine, because of some fortunate memory alignment (no kidding – I've seen such things not once).